# sql join table with its subtable

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose the following example table:

```
+-----+-----+-----+
| ID1 | ID2 | VAL |
+-----+-----+-----+
| A   | X   | 1   |
| A   | Y   | 2   |
| A   | Z   | 3   |
| B   | X   | 4   |
| B   | Z   | 5   |
| C   | Y   | 6   |
+-----+-----+-----+
```

Say I am interested in `ID1 = B` and would like compare it to others. The desired output would be:

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| REF.ID1 | OTH.ID1 | REF.ID2 | REF.ID2 | REF.VAL | OTH.VAL |  DIFF   |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| B       | A       | X       | X       | 4       | 1       |  3      |
| B       | A       | NULL    | Y       | NULL    | 2       | -2      |
| B       | A       | Z       | Z       | 5       | 3       |  2      |
| B       | B       | X       | X       | 4       | 4       |  0      |
| B       | B       | Z       | Z       | 5       | 5       |  0      |
| B       | C       | NULL    | Y       | NULL    | 6       | -6      |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Thank you.

Comment: My question is how to get the desired output. What could possibly be not clear?

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a cross join:

```
SELECT Ref.Id, Oth.id, ......
FROM dbo.tbl AS Ref
CROSS JOIN dbo.tbl AS Oth
WHERE Ref.Id = 'B';
```

For more information on joins check out my blog series here: http://sqlity.net/en/1146/a-join-a-day-introduction/

The Cross Join is described here: http://sqlity.net/en/1183/a-join-a-day-the-cross-join/

Comment: Somehow I can not come up with the working solution using `cross join`. Could you please use [this] (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/43b53/5) to find the answer?

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
SELECT  A.ID1 [REF.ID1],
        A.ID1 [OTH.ID1],
        CASE WHEN A.ID2 = B.ID2 THEN A.ID2 ELSE NULL END [REF.ID2],
        B.ID2 [OTH.ID2],
        CASE WHEN A.ID2 = B.ID2 THEN A.VAL ELSE NULL END [REF.VAL],
        B.VAL [OTH.VAL],
        CASE WHEN A.ID2 = B.ID2 THEN A.VAL ELSE 0 END - B.VAL [DIFF]
FROM (  SELECT *
        FROM YourTable
        WHERE ID1 = 'B') A
CROSS JOIN YourTable B
```

Comment: @danas.zuokas Ok, I see how the results don't match completely with the one you posted. But the reuslt you want has some inconsistencies, for example, how are we supposed to know wich row with `ID1='B'` needs to compare with the other 5 rows?, there is no clear way to do the join that you want